# Present Perfect after "before"

Tags: time, present-perfect

I've been watching a TV show recently and in one of the episodes the following is being said:

> I don't want half my army killed before I've crossed the Narrow Sea.

In the second part of the sentence, after "before", the Present Perfect tense is used, which made me think about the meaning of it.

How does "before" influence the meaning of this part of the sentence?

Comment: This is a counterfactual _before_; it refers to what one assumes will not happen if it is prevented beforehand. This produces odd syntactic conundrums, like how one expands _I'm glad my brother died before me_. It can't be _before I died_, because I'm still alive saying the sentence, but it also can't be _before I die_ because then it's a different verb and can't be deleted. Negatives complicate everything. If there's a negative in a sentence you're puzzled about, that's the thing to blame.

Comment: Wow. Great explanation! I will keep this in mind.

Comment: @JohnLawler: If you think *before I died* is counterfactual and can be prevented beforehand, I fear you will be disappointed one of these days.

Comment: @TimLymington: I'm putting my faith in senility to save me from disappointment!

Comment: No, not at all. There is temporal _before_ and there is counterfactual _before_, that's all. They have different meanings and different syntax. Like relative _which_ and interrogative _which_, or demonstrative _that_ and complementizer _that_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that he doesn't want half his army to be killed before he completely crosses the Narrow Sea. The present perfect here emphasizes on the completion of the crossing.

> I don't want to speak with you before I have chopped down this tree.

Until I completely finish the chopping, I won't utter anything to you.